# Simple number theory inequality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

$$-b < -r \leq 0\text{ and } 0 \leq r' < b     \implies    -b < r'-r < b$$

how is that implication possible? I'm going over the proof for the division theorem mainly the uniqueness part and it is that inequality and how it arises that is tripping me up. How can I consolidate them like that?

Comment: The sum of the two inequalities, because if $-r\leq 0$ and $r'<b$ then $r'-r<b$

Comment: HINT: you can sum two inequalities "componentwise"

Comment: for some reason or another it didn't dawn on me that you can sum them up componentwise.  gracias loco